# How to set animation to offset value in pie chart core plot api?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am implementing pie chart using core plot api, when i select the slice its move to up side, actually i am setting offset value in delegate method and by setting offset value the slice move to the up side. I want to set animation to that selected slice, Please help me how to set animation?